# Meaning and Purpose of " = '1' " in ContentResolver Query

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-query

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER " + " = '1''";
String[] selectionArgs = String.valueOf(1);
```

Why do we put `" = '1' "` in the Selecion Query ?

and Also the Reason for `String.valueOf(1);`

Comment: That doesn't look like valid Java code. Also please add more context to our code snippets. `selection` and `selectionArgs` don't seem to belong together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant this:

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(1)};
```

or this

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"1"};
```

or this

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '1'";
String[] selectionArgs = null;
```

or just this

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = 1";
String[] selectionArgs = null;
```

All four selections have the same results: Contacts that have a phone number.

SQLite (the database type that's used on Android) doesn't support Booleans (see [Datatypes in SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)), `true` and `false` are usually stored as integers `1` and `0`. So, to check if a boolean field is true you check if it has the value `1`.

Code snippets #1 and #2 use a [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) which contains a parameter or placeholder that's replaced with the first value of the `selectionArgs` array (since it's the first parameter in the query). This is a technique to protect against SQL injection and it often makes your queries better readable.
`selectionArgs` has to be an array of `String` values, so the integer value `1` in snippet #1 needs to be converted to a `String` first (using `String.valueOf(int)` actually only makes sense if you pass a variable rather than a constant number).

If you don't use any variables in your select statement you can just insert all values into the statement not using placeholders and `selectionArgs` as in code snippets #3 and #4. Since SQLite is dynamically typed it doesn't matter if you check for equality to `1` or `'1'`, the SQL interpreter will get it right either way.

Comment: It was a Dumb Question i just posted it without Studying the details of the query() method. Thanks though for answering.